# Update INI / properties file

Tags: java, ini

I have an INI file. It may contains sections and comments. I would like to read and update properties in Java code, while preserving the order of the properties and ini comments.

1. Using Java `Properties` class - not good enough, since it doesn't handle sections.
2. Using Apache `INIConfiguration` - doesn't preserve comments, properties that have value with # cannot be read.
3. Using ini4j - some of the comments are not preserved

Anyone has a suggestion how can I update only specific entry in an INI file?

Answer (score 1):

IniEditor preserves everything, including comments: https://github.com/nikhaldi/inieditor-java